# 3 phase cable equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-design, cables, three-phase, modelling

I am trying to build an equivalent circuit for a 3-ph+N cable. Could you help me to identify the parameters. In the picture, you can find the primitive impedance matric for the cable and the proposed equivalent circuit.

I got the shown imperative impedance matrix from a reference and the idea is to build an equivalent circuit for a cable that has the same parameters as in the matrix. I have trouble extracting the parameters of the equivalent from the shown matrix. Take into consideration this model for a 4-wire 50 Hz cable.

Many many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Why? and where did the picture come from? You should link to the author/creator of the picture/table.

Comment: The idea is to model it and add it to a low voltage network model with 50 Hz. So my first trial was selecting the diagonal elements as the impedance of each line which means R=0.211 and Xl=0.747. Now, what about the capacitance between the lines? or how I should model the other impedances in the given matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Oooh this is (not) fun. Didn't see it used for power transmission yet; As I see it, they attached an impedance meter between each of the ABCN (L1 L2 L3 N for us europeans) on the left and every other ABCN on the right, the recorded Z is put on the table. The matrix has to be symmetrical (otherwise the cable from a two port system view would be… interesting)

You actually didn't specify *the* single most important parameter, i.e. the working frequency.

The equivalent circuit you need to use is already given, a metric ton of phasor algebra will give you the values for the components (be careful with the parallel interactions). Probably *there is* a standard method for solving this (in the textbook from which the exercise comes, maybe) but you could actually attack it with K laws and linear circuit analysis. I'd start with the resistance part (which is straightforward) and then work out the inductive components.

Comment: Lorenzo Marcantonio  Many thanks for your reply. The idea is to model it and add it to a low voltage network model with 50 Hz. So my first trial was selecting the diagonal elements as the impedance of each line which means R=0.211 and Xl=0.747. Now, what about the capacitance between the lines? or how I should model the other impedances in the given matrix?

Comment: First of all the model isn't complete… the 0.049 wire-to-wire real impedance can't be modeled by capacitors between the lines, there's a resistive leakage to be handled (it's not trivial, too). Also keep in mind that, for example, when measuring A-B you have the AB capacitor *in parallel* with the *series* of BC and AC. And the neutral capacitor star, too has to be taken in consideration.

Comment: One last thing: this is a *lumped model* of the line. Depending on the purpose and on the length of the cable it would be probably better to use a *distributed model" and go toward a trasmission line approach. At 50Hz that would be over some 10km of cable; the theoretical approach is completely different (and a lot more advanced) but luckily spice can handle it. The idea is that you don't have a single LRC cell for the wire but you divide the cable in infinitely many LRCLRCLRC sections. See https://www.pspice.com/resources/application-notes/transmission-line-modeling

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio This, only a symmetrical, distributed model will do it. And some coupling, which is never easy to guess. I found out the hard way some time ago that cables are never as easy as a simple RLC(G) filter model.

Comment: concerned ditizen that's what I feared… usually I have these problems with transducer cables, when they are not something happy like a 4-20 loop. But at kilometers lengths power lines become like coax cables and should be modeled accordingly.